# How do you override Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Often I will want to render an ActionLink with content from the database (imagine an Id/Name combination) so I will put the following in my view:

```
        @foreach (var row in Model)
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(row.Name, "Action", "Controller", new { id = row.Id })</li>
        }
```

However, this throws an exception if the Name is an empty string.  Is there any way to prevent this.  I would like to override ActionLink, but it is an extension so I cannot override.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

First, I do not control the data, or I would ensure that the Name field is required and always populated.  Unfortunately this is not the case.

Second, I realize the user will have nothing to click on, but I believe that rendering an empty link is a better alternative than giving them a YSOD.

Comment: instead of copying all that code (in your answer), i created an extension for `HtmlHelper` `@Html.ActionLinkTranslated("Home", "Index", "Home", new { culture = WebApp.Helpers.CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture() }, null)` When it is called, if "Home" dosent exists in a translation, it returns the input ("Home")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that an instance method will always be preferred over an extension method with the same signature.

I was able to load a CustomHtmlHelper and put instance method ActionLink methods in the new class:

```
public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public new CustomHtmlHelper<T> Html { get; set; }

    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        Ajax = new AjaxHelper<T>(ViewContext, this);
        Url = new UrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext);

        //Load Custom Html Helper instead of Default
        Html = new CustomHtmlHelper<T>(ViewContext, this);
    }
}
```

And the HtmlHelper is as follows (ActionLink methods copied from Reflector without the LinkText error check:

```
public class CustomHtmlHelper<T> : HtmlHelper<T>
{
    public CustomHtmlHelper(ViewContext viewContext, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer) :
        base(viewContext, viewDataContainer)
    {
    }

    //Instance methods will always be called instead of extension methods when both exist with the same signature...

    public MvcHtmlString ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName)
    {
        return ActionLink(linkText, actionName, null, new RouteValueDictionary(), new RouteValueDictionary());
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues)
    {
        return ActionLink(linkText, actionName, null, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), new RouteValueDictionary());
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        return ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, new RouteValueDictionary(), new RouteValueDictionary());
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        return ActionLink(linkText, actionName, null, routeValues, new RouteValueDictionary());
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return ActionLink(linkText, actionName, null, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        return ActionLink(linkText, actionName, null, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(GenerateLink(ViewContext.RequestContext, RouteCollection, linkText, null, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes));
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string protocol, string hostName, string fragment, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, protocol, hostName, fragment, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string protocol, string hostName, string fragment, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(GenerateLink(ViewContext.RequestContext, RouteCollection, linkText, null, actionName, controllerName, protocol, hostName, fragment, routeValues, htmlAttributes));
    }
}
```

And finally, setting the pageBaseType int the `Views/Web.config` file to use the new custom WebViewPage:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    ...
    <pages pageBaseType="Fully.Qualified.Namespace.CustomWebViewPage">
    ...
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: You are still going to have links that can't be clicked if you don't replace that null string with something.  Just FYI.

Comment: Well aware! Thanks though :)

Comment: But when i'm try add for example `<pages pageBaseType="Business.Mvc.CustomWebViewPage">` he is write incorect_type_paramiter_number

Answer (score 4):

The issue you are going to have is if the name is blank, there is nothing to click on for the user in the UI.  Example:  `<a href="someUrl"></a>` gives no clickable object.

What may be better is if you could provide a default "No Name" string to those rows that have an empty string.

```
@foreach (var row in Model)
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(string.isNullOrEmpty(row.Name) ? "No Name" : row.Name, "Action", "Controller", new { id = row.Id })</li>
        }
```

**EDIT**

If you do not want to put a condition in every @Html.ActionLink, you can create your own @Html.Helper

```
 public static IHtmlString ActionLinkCheckNull(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string action, string controller, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
            var anchor = new TagBuilder("a") { InnerHtml = string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText) ? "No Name", linktext };
            anchor.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(action, controller, routeValues);
            anchor.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchor.ToString());
        }
```

Then in your Views folder web.config, add a reference to the namespace that you place this extension so you don't have to have a using statement at the top of every view.  Example:

```
<add namespace="Core.Extensions"/>
```

Then in your views, use

```
 @Html.ActionLinkCheckNull(row.Name, "Action", "Controller", new { id = row.Id })
```

Comment: Yes, I would prefer for the data to not have a empty link, but should it throw an exception and stop the whole page from loading? I was hoping for an elegant workaround that would not involve tacking a failsafe into every ActionLink

Comment: @MattMurrell - take a look at the explanation provided by Michael below on why its throwing out exceptions :)

Comment: Agreed.  Michael correctly states that it is not required to have a value and Microsoft included it as a "feature."  I even agree that the feature should often be on by default, it's probably a good idea.  I am just looking for a way to turn off said "feature" in my specific case.

Comment: @MattMurrell, the problem is that they use the `linkText` to build the actual text of the link. It wouldn't have any text and the user wouldn't be able to see anything. That's why they protected it.

Comment: @Michael & Tommy - Thanks for the help.  I understand why they do it.  The data that I am rendering comes from a third party and is sometimes blank.  I simply want to render it, without adding a failsafe to every single ActionLink in my code, and WITHOUT throwing an exception.

Comment: @MattMurrell, I'll show you how you can do that, give me a minute.

Comment: @MattMurrell, looks like Tommy and I had the same idea. :D

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - yup!  We wrote a few extensions to allow use to pass Html and Images to the Html.ActionLink() methods - figured it would help out here as well.

Answer (score 0):

To further concrete what Tommy is saying, I wanted to include the ultimately called method that's being protected:

```
private static string GenerateLinkInternal(RequestContext requestContext, RouteCollection routeCollection, string linkText, string routeName, string actionName, string controllerName, string protocol, string hostName, string fragment, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, bool includeImplicitMvcValues)
{
    string value = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(routeName, actionName, controllerName, protocol, hostName, fragment, routeValues, routeCollection, requestContext, includeImplicitMvcValues);
    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a")
    {
        InnerHtml = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText)) ? HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(linkText) : string.Empty
    };
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(htmlAttributes);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", value);
    return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

so, since you're building a link, the outer method is throwing an exception because **it wouldn't have any text to show on the screen.** That code is shown below:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "linkText");
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, htmlHelper.RouteCollection, linkText, null, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes));
}
```

technically speaking that code doesn't **have to be** protected but it is as a *feature*.

---

Here is a workaround for you, but you'll need to build your own `ActionLink` extension method like this and place it in a code file somewhere in the project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc.Resources;
using System.Web.Routing;
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class MyLinkExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, int identifier)
        {
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText) ? "some default text" : linkText, actionName, controllerName, new { id = identifier });
        }
    }
}
```

and so now your markup looks like this:

```
@foreach (var row in Model)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(row.Name, "Action", "Controller", row.Id)</li>
}
```

and you have encapsulated the turnary to determine the state of the `linkText` and yet still render your links in a single line.