# Add styling to all @Html.ActionLink from css class

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know I am able to add a class to a @Html.Actionlink by using, which acts on a *single* Actionlink at a time:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", 
                 "UpdateNote", 
                 "Notes", 
                 new { id = 0, type = (int)THOS.Utilities.Enumerations.Enumerations.Note.RelatedApplicationType.Law, appid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID, baseappid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID }
                 new { @class = "btn btn-primary icon-edit"},
                 null)
```

---

## However,

---

Is there a way of defining a class (much like adding a style to all divs in the css file like:

```
div{
color: red;
}

^ ^
| |
this way will act on *all* divs
```

instead of going

```
 <div class="myClass"></div>
```

I can just write:

```
<div></div>
```

which will automatically have `color:red` included

---

would there be a way of defining a class for an ActionLink without going to each actionlink and typing `@Class="myClass"`

---

## For Example

---

for adding styling for all button instances:

```
input[type="button"]{

background-color:red;
}
```

---

Can i do this with something like:

```
input[type="actionlink"]{

//styles for all actionlinks in project
}
```

and so all actionlinks can be written as:

@Html.ActionLink("Action","Controller")

and automatically include the styling stated in my css file?

---

I would do this the first way, but i've already ~100 made without defining a class, and don't fancy copy and pasting:

```
class="myClass"
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work just fine. A `tagname` is a valid `CSS` selector.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, sorry for my bad explanation. Yes, the first option works. However, it means i have to go through *every* actionlink within my project and adding the styling to *each* one seperately.

Comment: Why? If all of them are an `a` tag, `a { color: red; }` would match them all. You don't need to do a single thing in the `Razor` template.

Comment: I think I got your point now. You want `Razor` to add some kind of _attribute_ to the `anchors` generated by `@Html.ActionLink` to make them _different_ from regular `anchors`.

Comment: You got your answer here: [How do you override Html.ActionLink?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952240/how-do-you-override-html-actionlink)

Comment: I suggest you re-word your question title and content.

Comment: @MelanciaUK i don't really see the connection? could you clarify? Is that not about getting a 'null/error' value returned from the action, not about **styling** it?

Comment: The connection is that you need to override `Html.ActionLink` to add the extra attribute automatically. The override is there to achieve many other things, not just styles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

ActionLink generates just normal anchors, so you can write:

```
a{
   color:red;
}
```

But to get just ActionLinks you will need to call them by a class or a container.

Also may be a better way to do it is to create a custom ActionLink and put a default class inside and using this class you can do your selector, like this you will use this new Custom ActionLink and no need to copy paste classes.

```
public static class LinkExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyActionLink(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string linkText, 
        string action, 
        string controller
    )
    {
        var currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (action == currentAction && controller == currentController)
        {
            var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
            anchor.Attributes["href"] = "#";
            anchor.AddCssClass("currentPageCSS");
            anchor.SetInnerText(linkText);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchor.ToString());
        }
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, action, controller);
    }
}

%= Html.MyActionLink("hello foo", "Index", "Home") %>
<%= Html.MyActionLink("hello bar", "About", "Home") %>
```

Code copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5084672/20126

Comment: To expand on this though - that would work if you want to color ALL links, but there's no way to distinguish links which were generated by ActionLink versus those which weren't. Once the HTML gets to the browser, nothing is known about how it was generated.

Comment: @sphanley yes you are correct, he can get links he just want by a class, a container or any other selector.

Comment: @AmrElGarhy thanks for your suggestion - it's 90% there- but as sphanley has suggested, it causes *all* a tags to be given the styling, not just the Actionlinks

Comment: have edited the question for clarification, but are you suggesting to place  `anchor.AddCssClass("myClass");` somewhere in my project?

Comment: My suggestion is to create a custom ActionLink like html helper and you can set its class to be have a certain value by default, like this you can use this custom helper and then no need to put the class on each ActionLink in html.